# Axis2 fails in generation with wsdl2java and attribute in schema named class

Tags: java, apache-axis, axis

I'm having a huge bummer: 
I'm trying to generate a WS client with wsdl2java from axis2.
The problem is: in the underlying schema is an the following definition:

```
<xsd:attribute name="Class" type="ClassType">
```

That leads to the generation of a java class where an attribute "class" is defined and a javabean-style accessor is declard:

```
ClassType getClass ()
```

Well, you can see the problem ;)

getClass is already inherited by Object and declared final - so how do I get around that by using axis?

Thanks a lot for your help, I'm really stuck here!

Comment: provide the class, wsdl and the command that you are using when creating the clients.

Comment: Sorry, I can't the actual working files because of privacy issues, for constructing working examples I've got a lack of time. I'll provide the answer below

Answer (score 0):

The following command fixes the issue for me:

```
wsdl2java.bat -uri PHub.wsdl -d jaxbri -ssi
```

Since the default binding is ADB, I provide JAXB-style binding which circumnavigates the problem. JAXB generates the classes like ADB-style does also, but the resulting instance variable is named "clazz" and so the resulting getter is named getClazz() (instead of getClass which Object already provides finalized and ADB tries to overwrite what fails)